# Trigger Workflow in Task list

Tags: designer-workflow, task-list

I have a SP13 list that when changed triggers a list workflow that creates tasks in a tasks list. These tasks are not marked "wait for completion" because I want the workflow to end immediately.

Therefore there are no any automatic overdue reminders for these tasks. So, I created a list workflow in order to create reminders to items added in this Tasks list. The problem is that 2013 Workflows are not automatically triggered on item creation, when this item is created by a workflow. Note, I am not running as system account.

Comment: And...? what are you already did for that?

Answer (score 0):

Write list workflow on that other list. So when new item is added to that list do whatever processing you want to do because in the workflow you can access other lists may be by using Action  "Call Http "

Comment: "when new item is added" does NOT work when a task is created by workflow...

Comment: Is your workflow published as the system account? Workflows published by a system account can't start workflows on create in another list.

Comment: not a system account.

Answer (score 0):

> The workflow recursion prevention measure was put in place to mitigate
>   the following scenario:
>
> 1) We have two workflows and both activate on item updates in the same
>   list.
>
> 2) The workflow also updates list item in the list causing an infinite
>   loop of workflow activations.

[MSDN SharePoint 2013 WorkFlow Recursion Part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sridhara/archive/2014/08/19/fix-sharepoint-2013-workflow-recursion-prevention-part-1.aspx)

Part 2 of this article goes in detail about how to trigger a workflow from another workflow using the "Call HTTP Web Service" action in designer.

[MSDN SharePoint 2013 WorkFlow Recursion Part 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sridhara/archive/2014/08/21/fix-sharepoint-2013-workflow-recursion-prevention-part-2.aspx)

```
/_api/SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowInstanceService.Current/StartWorkflowOnListItemBySubscriptionId(subscriptionId='',itemId='')
```